# Function Pointer as Function Parameter

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, key, glfw

I've been writing a utility to work as a wrapper for GLFW Key Input.

I wanted to have a set of functions that would enable me to easily pass the key code and the function I wanted to be triggered upon the key being pressed or released.

I think everything here is right but I'm attempting to use it in my Game class and I'm getting the following error:

game.cpp(27): error C2664: 'void KeyManager::press(int,void *)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (__thiscall Game::* )(void)' to 'void *'
1> There is no context in which this conversion is possible

Game.cpp:

```
void Game::testKey()
{
    std::cout << "Key Up Pressed" << std::endl;
}

void Game::init()
{
    //  KEY MANAGER:
    KeyManager::initialize();
    KeyManager::press(GLFW_KEY_UP, &Game::testKey);
```

KeyManager.cpp:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include "global.h"
#include "key_manager.h"

namespace KeyManager
{
    std::map<int, int>                      keyAction;
    std::map<int, std::vector<void(*)()>>   pressFunctions;
    std::map<int, std::vector<void(*)()>>   releaseFunctions;

    static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        keyAction[key] = action;

        if (keyAction[key] == GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i != pressFunctions[key].size(); ++i)
            {
                (*pressFunctions[key].at(i))();
            }
        }

        if (keyAction[key] == GLFW_RELEASE)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i != releaseFunctions[key].size(); ++i)
            {
                (*releaseFunctions[key].at(i))();
            }
        }
    }

    void initialize()
    {
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    }

    void press(int keyCode, void(*listener)())
    {
        pressFunctions[keyCode].push_back(listener);
    }

    void release(int keyCode, void(*listener)())
    {
        releaseFunctions[keyCode].push_back(listener);
    }

    bool held(int keyCode)
    {
        if (keyAction[keyCode] == GLFW_PRESS || keyAction[keyCode] == GLFW_REPEAT)
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you take the address of a non-`static` member function you don't get back a "normal" pointer to function but rather a *pointer to member function*: Member functions do not just take the explicitly specified arguments as parameters but they also take an implicit pointer to the object (what becomes `this`) as parameter. Thus, the type of your `Game::testKey` is **not** `void(*)()` but it is rather `void (Game::*)()`, indicating that you still need to pass in a `Game` objects when calling this function.

If you can control the type of the functions being called, you are best off to use either a template argument for a function object or, if you need to store multiple of these object, a `std::function<Signature>` with a suitable type `Signature`, in your case probably `void()`: these objects can store an object and you can pass in the desired object, e.g.:

```
std::function<void()> fun(std::bind(&Game::testKey, this));
```

The `std::bind()` is a factory function taking a function as it first parameter and a set of arguments specifying the arguments the function should get when it is called. In the above example, the `Game::testKey` function gets the first argument bound to `this` (you can use whatever pointer to a `Game` object you want to use, of course).

When you don't really need an object to send the function to, you can also make the function `static` which results in a function which doesn't take an implicit object. Often the object is, however, actually required and just making the function `static` doesn't provide enough context.

Assuming that the `Game` object is needed for the context, the `KeyManager` would use `std::function<void(char)>` to report about key events (I also added a `char` parameter to get anof which key was used):

```
class KeyManager
{
    std::vector<std::function<void(char)>> handlers;
public:
    void addHandler(std::function<void(char)> h) {
        handlers.push_back(h);
    }
    //...
};
```

Later you can then add a handler function when you have a suitable `Game` object:

```
KeyManager m;
Game           g;
m.addHandler(std::bind(&Game::keyDown, &game));
```

Note that the `Game::keyDown` actually one uses the `Gane` object and no extra parameter: That's OK as the function object returned from `std::bind()` will just ignore additional arguments.

Comment: It sort of defeats the point if I'd have to create a a template/signature everytime I wanted to add a listener function to KeyManager. Is there anyway to have it work in the way I showed `KeyManager::press(GLFW_KEY_UP, &Game::testKey);` Possibly by making a change to the KeyManager functions?

Comment: @SyntheCypher: Yes, using a templated function object works very well and efficiently (as it can be inlined) when just using one function object. Thus, you'd use `std::function<Signature>` with a fixed `Signature` (e.g., `void()`), instead. As is written in the answer already.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still stuck on this, could you write a more full formed example of how that would be incorporated into KeyManager.cpp and Game.cpp?

Comment: I'm getting an issue it can't parse std::bind to std::function which is the addHandler argument.